# Validar DNI en Java

Tags: java

**¿Cómo validar un campo `jTextField` con el patrón-formato de un `DNI`?** Ejemplo: 72033197V

El **patrón** debe tener: **8 números + 1 letra** (12345678A).

He programado el siguiente código para validar un `DNI` y funciona. **¿Es la forma correcta de validación?**

**Código de prueba:**

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class validarDNI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dniIntroducido = null;
        Scanner miScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7,8}[A-Z a-z]");
        System.out.print("Introduce un DNI correcto: ");
        dniIntroducido = miScanner.nextLine();
        Matcher mat = patron.matcher(dniIntroducido);
        while(!mat.matches()){
           System.out.println("El DNI introducido es incorrecto, por favor introduzca un DNI válido.");
           System.out.print("Introduce un DNI correcto: ");
           dniIntroducido = miScanner.nextLine();
           mat = patron.matcher(dniIntroducido);
        }
        System.out.println("El DNI " + dniIntroducido + " es válido.");
    }
}
```

Bien, mi problema viene al importarlo en un `jTextField` para comprobar que tenga 8 números y una única letra. Y que al teclear la letra se convierta en mayúscula (`toUpperCase()`).

El `jTextField` se llama: `jTextField_DNI`.

He creado un evento `private void textfield_DNIKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {` para que vaya comprobando carácter a carácter pero... **¿Cómo lo implemento en el `jTextField`?**

```
private void textfield_DNIKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que vas a tener al ir comprobando caracter por caracter es que si validas cada vez que el usuario introduce un caracter, los primeros 7 van a resultar en `"DNI no válido"` aunque todo lo vaya escribiendo bien. Lo más recomendable es que valides cuando el `JTextField` pierde el foco, o bien, cuando el usuario le da en guardar, siguiente, o cualquier botón para continuar.

Para validar cuando pierde el foco le agregas un `FocusListener` al `JTextField` e implementas el método `focusLost`:

```
jTextField_DNI.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        String text = jTextField_DNI.getText();
        if(text != null) {
            // Valida text aquí
        }
    }
});
```

O si quieres caracter por caracter entonces agrégale un `KeyListener` al `JTextField` y escoge uno de los 3 métodos para implementar la lógica que quieres:

```
jTextField_DNI.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        String text = jTextField_DNI.getText();
        if(text != null) {
            // Valida text aquí
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final String dniChars="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";   
 private boolean validarDNI(String itDNI) {
            String intPartDNI = itDNI.trim().replaceAll(" ", "").substring(0, 7);
            char ltrDNI = itDNI.charAt(8);
            int valNumDni = Integer.parseInt(intPartDNI) % 23;
            if (itDNI.length()!= 9 && isNumeric(intPartDNI) == false && dniChars.charAt(valNumDni)!= ltrDNI) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            
        }
```

Con este método validas si la letra es correcta para la parte numérica, como sabes el módulo de la parte numérica (8 dígitos) de 23, responde a una letra que corresponde a un Carácter de la cadena dniChars